# How can I tunnel traffic from vpn to SSH?

Tags: ssh, vpn

I have:

1) PC - openvpn_connection - Server1(my server) - tunnel works fine i have internet on pc.

2) Server1(my) - SSH_tunnel - Server2 (not my) - proxy works fine, tested on browser internet works from server2.

I need: PC - vpn connection - Server1 - ssh tunnel - Server2 - Internet

Problem: I cant route traffic from vpn to ssh tunnel. Ive already tried sshuttle, but when i

> shuttle -r root@ip:port 0/0

internet connection on client crushed.
Also ive tried -x flag to exclude some interfaces, but this not helped me. Any ideas whats wrong?